# How to check a table exists in another schema

Tags: laravel, postgresql, schema, laravel-8, information-schema

How to check if a table exists in a given schema using laravel.

eg: I want to check if a table exists in acc schema
I tried this but did not get.

```
$apty_tblnme = 'acc.accounts_appropriation_allotment_types'; 

$apty_exist = (!Schema::hasTable($apty_tblnme));//--if table not, get 1,
```

Comment: Check the information schema, it’s made for things like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$apty_tblnme =  DB::connection('pgsql')
->select("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ? AND table_name = ?)",['acc','xxx']);

here,
acc-schema,
xxx- table name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).